# why git uses 32 bits number for storing time in index? is good idea make a lossy conversion?

Tags: linux, git, unix, rust

For learning purposes, I'm implementing git from scratch.

And in the process I have reached the part of the git index, and this the thing.

Git stores information about the index entry related to timing and others in 32-bit integers, for example each index entry has a `ctime` field that tracks last time a file was changed.

And here my confusion, I am working with rust and with the `libc` crate  and the interfaces it provides to obtain this information returns values in 64 bits.

And this raises me a couple  questions

First, is there a reason why the interfaces of `libc` and `git` are different? Why `libc` works with 64-bit registers and git with 32-bits registers? Is it really like that or am I missing something? There is some more fundamental concept that I don't see?

And mainly, How to approach this, how problematic would it be to make a lossy conversion? Is this a bad idea?

I mean the format in the git documentation specifies that these values are stored in 32 bits, therefore I have to work with 32 bit values, so it means that there is no other way out than to do a lossy conversion?

Comment: "Why libc works with 64-bit registers and git with 32-bits registers?" Don't confuse *values* with *registers*. `git`, like many tools, has to serialize and represent things on disk, and interchange with many platforms, 32-bit, 64-bit and perhaps otherwise.

Comment: I'm going to suppose based on the name `ctime` that this is just an encapsulation of a traditional UNIX time value (`time_t`) which has been 32 bits since January 1, 1970 and will be until [December 13th, 1901](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) when it has rolled over. As part of preparing for this roll-over, some libraries are, thankfully, taking pre-emptive measures to move to another representation, like 64-bit. Perhaps `git` is just lagging behind because it has to compile with other `libc` implementations that aren't ready yet.

Comment: thanks, I understand that as long as we do not reach the date that overflows the 32 bits and while the different systems finish migrating to a 64 bits representation the solution is a lossy conversion, and for learning purposes this is fine.

Comment: but I have a doubt I mentioned `ctime` as a one-off case but the same happens with the `dev (dev_t)` `inode (ino_t) ` and `file_size (off_t)` fields. Is it also a case of anticipation of future problems, or would doing some kind of lossy conversion on these fields give me any problems?

Comment: You should not be worried so much about 32 vs. 64 bits. You cannot change the on-disk format of the index anyway if you want to be compatible with stock Git. You should be worried more whether the values your library produces have the same meaning as those that must be written to the index and that stock Git expects to see there. If interoperability is not a concern, you can design your own index format. Or not have one at all if you dare to.